# Modified Bridge full wave Rectifier output

Tags: voltage

In the circuit diagram of the full wave rectifier given, if a diode D is connected between points X and Y, would the Output Voltage vs Time graph be different from that of the unmodified diagram?

[image: Circuit Diagram]

Comment: This strikes me as more appropriate to our [electronics.se] stack (our electronics site). You'd want to take their [tour] and read their [help] *before* posting - as you should on any site on the network.

Comment: Welcome! Please simulate it to build your understanding. There are several free ones out there, Falstad, LTspice to name two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's likely that a short-circuit arises on a half of the period[image]